# Inserir virgula em string em um arquivo cvs com Python

Tags: python, csv

Estou buscando uma maneira de inserir virgulas em um arquivo cvs que os elementos da lista, estão em ordem, mas não estão limitados com uma virgula.
[exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX7AG.png)

Dai quero inserir uma virgula após o nome, uma sequencia de carácteres, caso ocorrer um numero, inserir uma virgula antes desse numero. E depois de numero, e na ocorrência de espaço, colocar uma virgula na sequencia.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tendo em vista que o objetivo é ler o arquivo e trabalhar os dados e partindo do princípio que o arquivo está bem montado, use o [rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

Segue abaixo um pequeno exemplo para este caso:

```
with open("arquivo.txt", "r") as arquivo:
    linhas = arquivo.readlines()

for linha in linhas:
    print(linha.rsplit(" ", 7))  # Considerando que há 7 campos depois do nome
```

Caso você realmente queira colocar as vírgulas.

```
print(",".join(linha.rsplit(" ", 7)))
```

Comment: Acabei resolvendo o problema, com a ferramenta de importação de CSV do Excel. Mas agora testei aqui o rsplit com o 7, e funcionou.